# The easiest way to compare two imports of different formats

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I'm in the process of writing Jest unit test and need to compare two imports:

`import { StoreFinderMapComponent } from '@spartacus/storefinder/components'`

and

`import StoreFinderMapComponent from "@spartacus/storefinder/components"`

They do the same so the assertion should pass. But as you can see I can't just compare the strings as they don't match.

Is there a short/easy way of comparing them using ts api (ie. by ts-morph)? I know I can traverse, spread them to chunks and compare strings but perhaps there are nicer way. Using regexp is not an option, ts api has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In ts-morph if you have the `ImportDeclaration`, you can check if it has a default import via the condition:

```
importDecl.getDefaultImport() != null
```

There are also methods like `getNamespaceImport()` and `getNamedImports()`. What may be useful in this case is to use the lower level `getImportClause()` method in order to explore the import clause.

In the TS compiler API you have to always check the import clause and on it there's a `name` property for checking if the import declaration has a default import:

```
importDecl.importClause != null && importDecl.importClause.name != null
```

Looking at this in ts-ast-viewer might help for figuring things out ([See here](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZRtApgMWAOwCYqgWQEMwBhCcCTFTeAMynLgHIABAZzENkIGMBXNgHo2yKClpZcUQT3KQqNNkwBQoSLDgBvRKPSS8RUnMrV4AXzj1GrDlxi8Bw3RJx4ZxhTCVA)).